# 92 chevy truck distributor problems

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, distributor

I have a 92 chevy 350. Anywhere from a year to a month I have to replace the distributor. It starts cutting out around 2000 rpm but otherwise runs perfect. I have tried several other things to fix this issue and always end up replacing the distributor again runs great for a while then same issue. Has anyone had this problem. Maybe suggest a good brand of distributor.

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean the entire distributor down to the gear?  Not just the cap/rotor/coil/module?  Do you have any old ones where you can swap parts around?  How did you come to the decision to replace the distributor, was there play?

Comment: Yes the whole distributor assembly. I figured based on the way it cuts out I was not getting spark. I replaced the distributor and the problem was gone. Then came back a month later

Comment: I am not directly familiar with your engine, but I would think it would more likely be the an ignition module that would fail rather than the entire distributor. If you have old parts, you could try taking them apart and swapping parts around until you narrow down the piece that failed.  It is also possible it could be an electrical issue - broken wire, bad ground.

Comment: The ignition module is part of the pick up coil which is made onto distributor. It can be replaced separate. I have a warranty from when I bought the distributor originally. It just seems that maybe something is causing them to crap out or I have gotten a string of defective ones

Comment: I am going to check all the wiring tommorow

Comment: What brand of distributor? Sounds like a faulty (cheap part)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Have you verified that it is an ignition and not a low fuel pressure issue? Low fuel pressure can mimic  ignition issues, low power under load or while hot, high rpm miss or skip etc.